# Calculating statistics for discrete regions in feature collection using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am working on a script for calculating burn area statistics for multiple regions of interest using dNBR. The original script calculated burn area on a single region defined by a polygon and I've attempted to build upon it. I've gotten a bit stuck and seek some advice on the best way of approaching the following workflow.

The workflow I'm aiming for is:

- Import .shp containing buffers around points of interest
- Run script to calculate burn area statistics for each individual region
- Append resulting statistics (burn area in hectares for each burn severity class) to the feature collection and export the result.

Can .set be used with lists?

Desired fields to be added to the feature collection are: 'NA', 'High Severity', 'Moderate-high Severity', 'Moderate-low Severity', 'Low Severity','Unburned', 'Enhanced Regrowth, Low', 'Enhanced Regrowth, High'

Full script here:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/6151358ab2813de7ffe6831fb5b43cd2

Problem child in lines 272 to 312, visible below:

```
//                      ADD BURNED AREA STATISTICS FOR EACH OBJECT

// count number of pixels in entire layer
var allpix_hotspots =  classified.updateMask(classified);  // mask the entire layer

var pixstats_hotspots = allpix_hotspots.reduceRegions({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),               // count pixels in a single region
  collection: buffer,
  scale: 30 
  });
  
var allpixels_hotspots = ee.Number(buffer.get('sum')); // extract pixel count as a number

// create a function to derive extent of one burn severity class
// arguments are class number and class name
var areacount_hotspots = function(cnr, name) {
 var singleMask_hotspots =  classified.updateMask(classified.eq(cnr));  // mask a single class
 var stats_hotspots = singleMask_hotspots.reduceRegions({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),               // count pixels in a single class
  collection: buffer,
  scale: 30
  });

// severity classes
var names2 = ['NA', 'High Severity', 'Moderate-high Severity', 'Moderate-low Severity', 'Low Severity','Unburned', 'Enhanced Regrowth, Low', 'Enhanced Regrowth, High'];

var pix_hotspots =  ee.Number(stats_hotspots.get('sum'));
var hect_hotspots = pix_hotspots.multiply(900).divide(10000);                // Landsat pixel = 30m x 30m --> 900 sqm
var perc_hotspots = pix_hotspots.divide(allpixels_hotspots).multiply(10000).round().divide(100);   // get area percent by class and round to 2 decimals
buffer.set({names2: hect_hotspots});
};

// execute function for each class
for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  areacount_hotspots(i, names2[i]);
  }
  
print(buffer);
```